# How do I insert new items to the listbox the other way around?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I have a program that puts items on a list. I need a way to always keep the newest item on top. In C++ there is a command called **push** for a similar feature so I guess I'm looking for something like that.

I tried doing main.listIndex -= 1 but that didn't work out. Code:

```
self.recievingAdress.insert(main.listIndex, "orange")
main.listIndex += 1
self.recievingAdress.insert(main.listIndex, "apple")
```

**Expected** results:

> *orange*
>
> *apple*

**Actual** results:

> *apple*
>
> *orange*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an item in the last position of the list, you can try  : `list.insert(END, item)`

```
self.recievingAdress.insert(END, "apple")
```

Comment: That appears to be doing the same thing, is there anything opposite to 'END'?

Comment: So basically I want it to be on the first position of the list, not the last.

Comment: Try a affectation : 
listIndexBox = main.listIndex  //// 
self.recievingAdress.insert(listIndexBox, "orange")  ////
listIndexBox += 1  ////
self.recievingAdress.insert(listIndexBox, "apple") ////